# Why isn't my module in the otuput folder?

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10, yarnpkg

Consider these files:

**mymodule.mjs**

```
export const answer = 42
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "rootDir": "src",
      "outDir": "lib",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "declarationMap": true,
      "inlineSources": false,
      "declaration": true,
      "stripInternal": true,
      "lib": [
        "es2016",
        "dom"
      ],
      "strict": true,
      "noImplicitReturns": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true
  },
  "include": [
      "src"
  ]
}
```

the package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "deleteme2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc", 
    "build": "yarn run compile",
    "start": "node lib/server.mjs",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

It compile sucessfully with:

`$ yarn run build`

However, when I try to start it `yarn run start` I get the error:

```
$ node lib/server.mjs
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\deleteme2\lib\server.mjs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Why isn't the `server.mjs` in the output folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're trying to compile `.mjs` file with `tsc`.

`tsc` only supports `.ts,.tsx` files since it's meant to be used to compile `TypeScript` to `JavaScript` only. So you can not use it to compile `.mjs,.js` or any other file types.

If you change your file to `mymodule.ts` and put it inside `src/` (because you only include `src` in your `tsconfig.json`), then it should work as expected. In this case the output file will be in `.js`, so you need to run `node lib/myModule.js` instead.

Comment: that simple, can't believe I missed that :)